# Cargar página PHP en un contenedor

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

tengo un formulario el cual grafica los datos de una consulta en una página nueva, pero quiero que esta gráfica se muestre en un div de un html.

Hice esta función de JS

```js
function grafica(){
  $('#contenedor').load('graf.php')
}
```

Mi consulta la hace bien puesto que en la nueva pestaña se grafica bien, el problema viene cuando ese PHP lo quiero cargar dentro de otra página, me indica el error "Undefined index: f1"

Comment: ¿Dónde te marca el error, PHP o Javascript? Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/513936/edit) para agregar el mensaje de error completo y el código donde aparece.

Comment: Ya la edité, espero me dé a entender jeje

Comment: Seguramente graf.php está esperando algun dato por $_POST o $_GET que no le estas dando.  Cuando lo abres en la pestaña ¿lo abres tal cual o debes introducir algun dato específico?  Ya sea un simple login seria suficiente para que te de el problema. Piensa que un `<div>` no es un iframe.

Comment: Y ahora que te leo mejor me reafirmo en que tienes un problema al intentar hacer el `load`, pues al hacerlo así no le estas mandando datos del formulario.  Para conseguir lo que quieres debes hacerlo por [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), no por `load`

Comment: @EmmanuelHernández, te faltó agregar el código PHP de la página donde se genera el error y casi estoy seguro que el problema es como dice masterguru.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si lo pude solucionar con Ajax

Comment: @EmmanuelHernández perfecto, me alegro.  Si acaso pon tu misma una respuesta a tu pregunta explicando minimamente lo que hicistes para solucionarlo, y tu misma podras aceptarla en unas 12 horas (sí, se pueden aceptar tus propias respuestas, pero pasado un tiempo prudencial) o bien elimina la pregunta para que no quede pendiente de responder para siempre, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solo tuve que hacer un script con ajax con unos id que asigné en mis campos

```js
<script> 
  $('#Enviar').click(function(){
      var Fechain=document.getElementById('f1').value;
      var Fechafin=document.getElementById('f2').value;

      var ruta="Fein="+Fechain+"&Fefin="+Fechafin;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'graf.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ruta,
      })

      .done(function(res){
        $('#respuesta').html(res)
        $('#f1').val('');
        $('#f2').val('');
      })

      .fail(function(){
        console.log("error");
      })
      .always(function(){
        console.log("complete");
      })
  });  

</script>
```

Comment: Trata de explicar mejor como lo resolviste